# Golang gorm union function for orm approach

Tags: go, union, grails-orm

I am trying to union two results with each other the sql-query I could use for would look like this:

```
SELECT id, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at, user_id, friend_id 
FROM public.friendlists where user_id = $1
union all 
SELECT id, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at, user_id, friend_id
FROM public.friendlists where friend_id = $1
```

I know I could just use the sql statement or just join the two results. I just want to find out a way because im curious how to handle this and to avoid hardcoded sql statements.
The following code is what I have so far:

```
db.Where(&models.Friendlist{UserId: userID}).
Or(&models.Friendlist{FriendId: userID}).
Order("created_at desc").
Find(&result)
```

How I could I do this with an ORM approach in gorm? Or is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think union is implemented in gorm.

but you can execute raw query with union and marshal result into structure required via this method - https://gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html#Raw-SQL